# Find the equation of the parabola with focus (6,0) and directrix x=0

Tags: conic-sections

Find the equation of the parabola with focus $\ (6,0) $ and directrix $\ x=0 $

---

What I have done so far:

$ (x-h)^2 = 4p(y-k)  $

$ (h,k) = (3,0) $

$ (x-3)^2 = 12y $ as p = 3

However, the answer shows that it's $ y^2=12x-36 $

Comment: The right side should be squared and not the left side just look at the directrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start with $(x-h)^2 = 4p(y-k)$, you presuppose that the parabola is vertical. But here, the directrix is vertical, and so the parabola is horizontal.

Does this give you the next step?